# Proving General Version of Additivity for the Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am working through some real analysis exercises, and am currently stumped on the following problem:

Let $f \in \mathscr{R}([a,b]).$ Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be arbitrary real numbers in $[a,b],$ not necessarily ordered in any way. Prove that
$$ \int_\alpha^\gamma f = \int_\alpha^\beta f + \int_\beta^\gamma f. $$ (Remember what $\int_a^b f$ means if $b\leqslant a$).

It seems fairly obvious, but I can't figure out how to prove it. I tried dividing it into cases, depending on whether $\alpha, \beta,$ and $\gamma$ or less than or greater than each other, but that seems overly complicated. I also tried applying the regular additivity for the integral, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone offer some advice on how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: What is your definition of $\int_\alpha^\beta f$? And what do you call "the regular additivity for the integral"?

Comment: This textbook defines it as $\int_a^b f := \int_a^b f(x)dx = \underline{\int_a^b }f(x)dx = \overline{\int_a^b}f(x)dx.$ i.e., $f$ integrable being equal to the lower and upper Darboux integrals. For regular additivity, I mean that for a function $f$ integrable on $[a,b],$ and if $a < c < b$, then $f$ is integrable on $[a,c]$ and on $[c,b],$ and $\int_a^b f = \int_a^c f + \int_c^b f.$

Comment: If you are allowed to use this property, there is little work left...

Comment: Probably so, I think i'm just getting bogged down by the fact that we dont know if $\alpha < \beta < \gamma$

Comment: There are only 6 cases.